# Get selected Value from dropdownlist after submit?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, drop-down-menu

I populate DropDownList in ASP.NET webforms:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="salesman"></asp:DropDownList>


users= Buslayer.GetSalesRep();

foreach (userentity user in users)
{         
      salesman.Items.Add(new ListItem(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
                                      user.UserID.ToString())); 
}
```

After submission, I am still getting selected index = 0,

I tried all of this but failed:

```
Response.Write("" + salesman.SelectedValue);
Response.Write("" + salesman.SelectedItem.Value);
Response.Write("" + salesman.SelectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking for the Page posting back with you databind?

Your page load should look something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }

}

protected void BindData()
 {
    // Get your data
    ddl.DataSource = yourData;
    ddl.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: i think it is not related to that:
if(Page.IsPostBack)
Response.Write("" + salesman.SelectedIndex);

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
Response.Write("" + salesman.SelectedValue);
both doesnt work